Current User in Models scala playframework 2.8
I'm currently working on a web application using Play Framework 2.8 with Scala. In this application, I need to log which user is performing updates in the models or repositories. However, the system is quite large, and it's not feasible to propagate the user ID from the controller to the models.
I'm seeking a solution to inject the current user into the repository without passing it explicitly from the controller. This requirement is related to a previously asked question, which you can find here: Current Request/User details in Models in Scala Play! 2.5

However, the system is quite large, and it's not feasible to propagate the user ID from the controller to the models. You mean it will take some hours of work but there's nothing preventing it technically. Right?

I don't think there's any way out if you don't want to propagate the data from the controllers layer. Propagation could happen via implicits. But still you'll have some code to implement. Otherwise you'd have to implement some "magic" to propagate it automatically when chaining Futures/switching threads, but that will be more code and more obscure.
